# How can I create a build system in Sublime Text to run my python code in an IDLE shell?

Tags: python, sublimetext3, python-idle, build-system

How can I run my code from Sublime Text in an IDLE shell. I much prefer using IDLE to run my code when I'm writing it because it's really easy to debug. However I love Sublime Text and much prefer to actually write the script with it.

I'm trying to create a build system which runs my code with IDLE3.

However, when I do this, it simply opens an IDLE shell but doesn't run my file.

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/idle3.8"
}
```

And when I do this it opens my script with IDLE but doesn't run in the shell.

```
{
    "shell_cmd": ["/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/idle3.8","$file"]
}
```

How can I get it to run the file in an IDLE shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked it out.

It's done like this:

```
{
    "cmd": ["/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/idle3", "-r", "$file"]
}
```

The example on the docs shows `"-d"` and it opens in debug mode so I had an educated guess and replaced it with `"-r"` which I guess means 'run'?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/idle.html#command-line-usage shows that adding '-r' should work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the question and the subsequent answer, simplified my search a lot.

A simple basic guide for anyone looking to do this in the future:

**1. Create a build system**

Go to `Tools->Build System->New Build System...`
Enter the following:

```
{
    "cmd":["**PATH-TO idle file**", "-r","$file"],
    "selector": "source.python"  //Optional - Used when Tools | Build System | Automatic is set to true
}
```

In windows Path to Idle File for this is : `"C:\\Program Files\\Python311\\Lib\\idlelib\\idle.bat"` or something similar

**2. Save the build system**
Save it as `"*Your-Build-System-Name-Here*.sublime-build"`. It should normally get saved to `~\Sublime Text\Packages\User folder`. Be careful about where you save, as SublimeText only checks for `.sublime-build` files in Packages folder for enumerating the build systems list

Your build system is ready. It should show up in the build systems list `Tools->Build System` with whatever you named the .sublime-build file. If it doesn't, close and reopen sublime text.

**3. Test if it works**

Open a simple python file with some code that has a print function like

```
for i in range(100):
    print i
```

and press *Ctrl+B*
Your script should run in an IDLE window.

If that does nothing, press *Ctrl+Shift+B*, it should let you select your build system then run the code. If that also doesn't work, you can go to `Tools-> Build System` and change to your build system, and then do *Ctrl+B*

**Optional Step**

Building usually opens an output window. You can go to `Preferences->Settings` and add the line `"show_panel_on_build": true,`to disable it.

Be warned that this is an all-or-nothing step, it will turn off the output window for all build-systems. There currently isn't a way to set the option for a single build=sysem only as far as I know.